# Regex to parse number text and bracketed text from string

Tags: regex, string

I need a regular expression to match parts of a string, some of which are optional.

Strings can be in the following formats:

"this is a string" -- match "this is a string"

"1.20.3 this is a string" -- match "1.20.3" and "this is a string"

"1.20.3 this is a string [plus more]" -- match "1.20.3", "this is a string", and "plus more"

Comment: Great, so, have you already started on it? Could you share your drafts?

Comment: `[\d.]+|\w[\w\s]*\w|(?<=\[)[\w\s]*(?=])`

Comment: What environment are we talking about?

Comment: Just to let you know: there can be several ways to do it, but a lot depends on what your requirements are. Without them and without seeing what you tried makes it difficult to help you appropriately and fast. It is always necessary to know the language you are using since regexes differ across flavors/libraries/languages.

Comment: Show what you've tried

Comment: At least let us know the regex engine. See [`^(?:([\d.]+)\s)?(.+?)\s*(\[.*\])?$`](https://regex101.com/r/uB1xI8/1). Does it work the way you expect?

Answer (score 1):

What about this one: `(?:[\w ]+)|(?:[\d\.]+)`. Obviously with a global flag.

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/xW2kS6/1).